# Displaying multiple images with patches overlayed in the same figure in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image I overlay with a patch and I want to be able to display multiple images on the same figure all with different over-layed patches. I tried using the subplot command but it did not work. I defined my axes and parent figure below.

```
hFig = figure;
hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);
hAx2 = axes('Parent',hFig);

fh = figure('units','pixels',...
          'position',[300 300 440 500],...
          'menubar','none',...
          'name','SliderTool',...
          'numbertitle','off',...
          'resize','off');


subplot(1,2,1) imshow(image1,'Parent','hAx');
patch(....,'parent', 'hAx');
subplot(1,2,2) imshow(image2,'Parent','hAx2');
patch(....,'parent', 'hAx2');
```

This is the basic idea for what I want to do but for some reason I cannot get it to work. Am I using the handles incorrectly?

Comment: Are you wanting to show the images in the same panel of the figure?  Or is doing it in subplots acceptable?

Comment: Different panels on the same figure is preferred but subplots would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
image1 = imread('street1.jpg');
image2 = imread('street2.jpg');

ha1 = subplot(1,2,1) ;
imshow(image1);    
X = get(ha1,'Xlim')/2;
Y = get(ha1,'Ylim')/2;    
patch(X([1 2 2 1]),Y([1 1 2 2]),'m','FaceAlpha',0.5,'parent', ha1 );

ha2 = subplot(1,2,2) ;
imshow(image2);
X = get(ha2,'Xlim')/2;
Y = get(ha2,'Ylim')/2;    
patch(X([1 2 2 1]),Y([1 1 2 2]),'b','FaceAlpha',0.3,'parent', ha2);
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this will solve what you're trying to do but I think it will give you a point in the right direction.

[Subplot option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html)

[Imshow/subimage option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f10-43158.html#brbuwuj-4)

You might also need to use [Hold](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) to apply the patch without replacing the image that you are displaying first.